# jUnit, Embedded Tomcat and Hibernate java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, junit, jersey

I have this very interesting issue that has been making me tear down my hair for the past two days.

I am using **jUnit** and an **embedded Tomcat** to test some API endpoints (**Jersey**).
I'm not a big fan of mocking and I made this setup to test the API responses in conditions as close as possible to production.

When the API receives a call, it should supply a response accordingly (found, not found, etc). This is where **Hibernate** comes in.

When I run this on my Tomcat set up in eclipse, or when I deploy the build (Maven) on a standalone Tomcat on the remote server, everything works fine, but when the API is called on the embedded Tomcat during the test I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.models.listing.Listing cannot be
> cast to com.models.listing.Listing

Yes, it's the same class name.

To retrieve the Listing object I use the Hibernate standard of getting a persisted object by ID

```
Listing listing = session.get(Listing.class, ID);
```

This is how the embedded tomcat setup looks like:

```
public void start(String appName) throws Exception {
    File root = getRootFolder();
    System.setProperty("org.apache.catalina.startup.EXIT_ON_INIT_FAILURE", "true");
    Path tempPath = Files.createTempDirectory("tomcat-base-dir");
    
    tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(0);
    tomcat.enableNaming();
    tomcat.setSilent(true);
    tomcat.setBaseDir(tempPath.toString());
    
    tomcat.getHost().setDeployOnStartup(true);
    tomcat.getHost().setAutoDeploy(true);
    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(tempPath.toString());
    
    File webContentFolder = new File(root.getAbsolutePath(), "src/main/webapp/");
    if (!webContentFolder.exists()) {
        webContentFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("default-doc-base").toFile();
    }
    
    StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/" + appName, webContentFolder.getAbsolutePath());
            
    //Disable TLD scanning by default
    if (System.getProperty(Constants.SKIP_JARS_PROPERTY) == null ) {
        System.out.println("disabling TLD scanning");
        StandardJarScanFilter jarScanFilter = (StandardJarScanFilter) ctx.getJarScanner().getJarScanFilter();
        jarScanFilter.setTldSkip("*");
    }
    
    System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + webContentFolder.getAbsolutePath());
    
    // Declare an alternative location for your "WEB-INF/classes" dir
    // Servlet 3.0 annotation will work
    File additionWebInfClassesFolder = new File(root.getAbsolutePath(), "target/classes");
    WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
    
    WebResourceSet resourceSet;
    if (additionWebInfClassesFolder.exists()) {
        resourceSet = new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes", additionWebInfClassesFolder.getAbsolutePath(), "/");
        System.out.println("loading WEB-INF resources from as '" + additionWebInfClassesFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "'");
    } else {
        resourceSet = new EmptyResourceSet(resources);
    }
    resources.addPreResources(resourceSet);
    ctx.setResources(resources);
    
    //start tomcat
    tomcat.start();
}
```

And this is how the Hibernate configuration looks like:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    // setup the session factory
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    
    //add annotated classes
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Listing.class);
    
    //connection properties
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://<some IP>:3306/<some db name>");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "<some username>");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "<some password>");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
    
    //sql properties
    configuration.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
    configuration.setProperty("format_sql", "true");
    
    //misc properties
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
    
    //c3p0 properties
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "1");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "10");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "100");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "1000");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.validate", "true");
    
    //return null
    return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

To summarize, the test starts in jUnit, the embedded tomcat instance fires up and with a REST client I send a request to an API endpoint. The endpoint responds after it retrieves the resource from Hibernate.

Dependency versions:

> Glassfish Jersey 2.23
>
> jUnit 4.11
>
> Tomcat embedded 8.5.3
>
> Hibernate 5.2.1

My best bet is some issue with the class loader.
I know that the JVM sees classes as different if they were loaded with different class loaders even if it's basically the same class from the same package and so on, but I just don't seem to find a way to make this work.

Maybe my hypothesis is completely off and I am missing something here, so if anyone has encountered something like this or has some suggestions (I already tried tens of "solutions") please jump in.

Thanks everyone for the help in advance!

Comment: bro having this same problem. and I am lost.

Answer (score 2):

I still didn't figure out the mystery and I just let go after some other "trial and error" ideas with class loaders and so on.

I "fixed" it by downgrading to hibernate 4.3.11